# Symbols in MapServer

Tags: symbology, mapserver

I was just trying to render a point layer with classes using a symbol circle.  Below is the part of the code.

```
DATA 'E:\SBI\GIS\Growth\Growth11-12.shp'
METADATA
  'ows_title' 'Growth11-12'
END
STATUS on
TRANSPARENCY 100
PROJECTION
'proj=longlat'
'datum=WGS84'
'no_defs'
END
CLASSITEM 'GROWTH SCA'
CLASS
  NAME "GROWTH SCA = 0_POOR" 
  EXPRESSION "0_POOR" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 5.25 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 255 0 0
   END
END
CLASS
  NAME "GROWTH SCA = 1_BAD" 
  EXPRESSION "1_BAD" 
   STYLE
     SYMBOL "circle" 
     SIZE 5.25 
     OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
     COLOR 212 42 0
   END
END
```

The other polygon layer renders fine. But this particular point layer doesn't render and throws the following error message:

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named
> 'Growth11-12'. msLoadMSRasterBufferFromFile(): General error message.
> unable to open file /ms4w/apache/htdocs/xyz/map/circle for reading.

Could anyone suggest what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your "circle" symbol is not defined, you can add it with:

```
symbol
  type ellipse
  points 1 1 end
  name "circle"
end
```